# Can't login to Instagram Account with Instabot

Tags: python, instagram

I am normally signed in on instagram on my account, but when I try running it with Instabot it pops this error: Error type: block_eu_user_login_in_old_app

Any Idea how to fix this?

Tried changing my password. Didn't work

Comment: can you post your code pls?

Comment: `block_eu_user_login_in_old_app` suggests this probably has something to do with the changes they recently made for users in the EU, regarding handling of cookies & collecting user data. (But I couldn't tell you what to do about it, whether you might need to do something within your account, like accept some additional consent banner first; or if perhaps the Instabot itself needs an update first to handle this new situation ... dunno.)